# Control multiple led light in raspberry pi by python

Tags: python

it shows an error:
ParseError: bad input on line 27

how can i fix it? can someone help me.
This will be the code for the raspberry pi and the user can enter the input to change the led light from a colour to another colour

the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

LEDa=17 #red
LEDb=18 #green
LEDc=22 #yellow

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(LEDa, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LEDb, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LEDc, GPIO.OUT)

print "Do you want to feed the pet?"
print "1: Yes"
print "2: No"
ledaction = input("Make your choice: ")
        
if ledaction==1:
        GPIO.output(LEDc, True)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(LEDc, False)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(LEDb, True)
        time.sleep(4)
        GPIO.output(LEDb, False)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(LEDc, True)

if ledaction==2:
        GPIO.output(LEDc, True)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(LEDc, False)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(LEDa, True)
        
else:
        GPIO.output(LEDc, True)


GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Which line is 27?

Comment: i guess it's because you are comparing a string from your input with an integer. convert one of them to theo other!

Comment: time.sleep(4) that line